# how to make performance monitor on in VS 2015?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015

I am working on Visual studio 2015. When I started first the performance monitor was displayed. I closed it for some reason and not able to get it again . Someone please tell me where it is located in Menu?

Comment: The panel is empty now, does anyone knows how to get that performance graph back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug > Windows > Show Diagnostic Tools

Comment: Thanks... I was looking into View.

Comment: But its empty now. Not showing any performance graph. How to get that?

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl-Alt-F2` or: `Debug` -> `Windows` -> `Show Diagnostic Tools.`

[image]

> note: You can also save multiple window layouts and switch between
>   them by using the `Window` menu option

Comment: Thanks .Wawoo... I did not know that. very useful